# MySQL - Index on suffix of string

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am storing email addresses in a column as `varchar` and I will be making queries to select emails based on the the suffix (the domain name). So for example:

```
---------------
EMAIL 
---------------
test@gmail.com
hello@aol.com
hi@yahoo.com
tester@aol.com
```

I want to be able to efficiently select all emails with "aol.com" suffix, for example – and there could eventually be millions of records matching the query. Is there an efficient way to do this, or would it be better to just create another column and store just the suffix and add an index to that column?

Comment: You already know the answer to this: create another column and index it.

Comment: I already know that is viable solution yes, but I would rather do it with the existing column if an efficient solution exists.

Comment: mySql does not provide an indexing-function for this sort of search (you might try FULLTEXT index though - I don't know if it performs well and if it uses @ and . as word separators). Also partitioning will not work with this sort of criteria. The most efficient way would be to create a seperate column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL allows indexes on *prefixes* of strings, that are of fixed length.  That doesn't quite help you, but it comes sort of close.

You can also try a full-text search on the column.  You want to be sure that `@` is *not* considered a word character (hence it is a separator) and probably that `.` *is* considered a word character.  If you do this, you can use `match against` on the domain.

However, it is probably easiest to add a new column and assign the value and index:

```
alter table t add column domain varchar(255);

update t
    set domain = substring_index(email, '@', -1);

create index idx_t_domain on t(domain);
```